# Can I define a default order for an @Entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, annotations

For example,

```
@Entity
class Foo {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    int priority;
    ...
}
```

I want `HibernateTemplate.loadAll(Foo.class)` to order by `priority` by default, is it possible with annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Generally annotations are not supposed to affect queries that return a list of entities (annotations affect the behaviour of a single entity)

You can use an HQL/JPQL query to get ordered entities:

```
 SELECT f FROM Foo f ORDER BY f.priority
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki it achieves the desired effect, because there's no way similar to what he likes.